# How to find number of days and nights between 2 give datetime in java script?

Tags: javascript

How to fine total number of days and nights between 2 given datetime in java script.

For Example if I am giving input as -

```
 date1=2013-11-10 21:26:36
 date2=2013-11-12 23:26:36
```

It should give output as **2-days and 3-nights**.

I am new to java-script and facing problem in how to start this function. please help.
I have googled but not found any code or way to make this functoin.

Comment: Have a look at http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Have a look at [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/542938/218196) and additionally check the time to find out whether to include the start and end date or not.